# How would you template for Infinite Scroll?

Tags: templating

I want to integrate Waypoints JS's Infinite Scroll instead of using traditional pagination.  I think the Straight Up Craft site uses this approach on its blog.

How might you template the following HTML to work with CraftCMS?  I know how to limit or not limit the number of entries, but how do you template to load each successive group of (say) 12 entries as you reach a waypoint - that is the "infinite-more-link"?

```
<div class="infinite-container">
<div class="infinite-item">
<div class="infinite-item">
<div class="infinite-item">
...</div>
<a class="infinite-more-link" href="/next/page">More</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  Using the CraftCMS paginate example - I just needed to add the pagination url for the next page.